# Level-shifting with limited ways to change the board

Tags: mosfet, zener, level-shifting, hacking

I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9hu7N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where:

- U1 is an MCU powered at 3.3V
- OUT is a GPIO
- the dashed box represents an external hardware that I cannot change (the P-mosfet is a BSS84)

I only can:

- remove R1 or change it's value but I cannot change the component type (it's a part of an array of resistors in CAY16)
- place any 2-pins component in between (there are two THT pads)
- place a 0603 component between OUT and GND

The goal is to turn on the P-Mosfet.
Of course I would know how to solve it if I could modify the board freely.
Please note, this is just a one-shot hack to adapt an existing board that cannot be bought again.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to pull-down the gate to 0V without let the +5V to reach the MCU.

My idea is to put a 2V zener diode in between, with the K towards the gate.
When the GPIO is high, the voltage across the diode is 5V-3.3V=1.7V so the zener is still open.
If the GPIO goes low, the voltage across the diode would be 5V so it conducts forcing 2V on the gate. 2V is the maximum VGS(th) of BSS84 so it should turn on... Perhaps I can try with a 1.8V zener diode but I would leave a few hundreds of mV to be safe.

What do you think about?

Comment: What is your MCU?

Comment: xmega64A3, not 5V tolerant...

Comment: I say your zener idea is actually the old cheap industry standard way to do that :D

Comment: @Mark Since it's a one-off you might chance it with a 470R in series and OD output anyway. Without R1 of course.

Comment: @JanDorniak, the 470R would protect the MCU when the internal diode conducts?

Comment: It would limit the current as not to damage it. But it might not work and lead to weird stuff like latch-ups.